# using servlet filter with session variable

Tags: session, jsf-2, servlet-filters

I have created a Java web application using JSF 2.
When a user login to my application, I store his identifier in the session, so:

```
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("userid", myBean.getUserId());
```

Then I created my filter:

```
public class PageFilter implements Filter {

private FilterConfig filterconfig;

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    this.filterconfig = filterconfig;
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest httprequest =(HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse httpresponse =(HttpServletResponse) response;
    HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession();

    String userid = (String) session.getAttribute("userid");

    String pageRequested = httprequest.getRequestURI();

    try {
        if( userid != null && pageRequested.contains("index.xhtml") ) {

            System.out.printf("User authenticated with " + httprequest.getRemoteUser() + " username conected.");
            httprequest.getRequestDispatcher("/service/home.xhtml").forward(request, response);

        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }catch(IOException | ServletException e){
        //do something
    }

}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    System.out.print("Existing from loginFilter");
}
```

}

My scope is to manage the refresh button of the browser so if user is already logged then user is redirected to /service/home.xhtml. Also, the url in my web application is always:

```
localhost:8080/myapplication
```

So if user browses the site among all the pages, the url is always that (the action is hidden).
The problem is that if user clicks on the url in the browser, the request is for index.xhtml and my session is null (I cannot get user identifier by session.getAttribute("userid");).

Where is my fault?
The index.xhtml is defined as welcome-file-list in my web.xml:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Thanks.

Comment: If the session is null you most likely need to create it since nothing needed a session and hence the servlet container just did not create one yet

Comment: The session is null only when user refresh the page or select the url on the browser and then click enter

Comment: Then try to find out WHY it is null. Not a JSF issue.

Comment: If I knew......

Comment: Debug? check session cookies, check if the order things are called in is ok... Check the mappings for the filter... and more. I have sort of a deja-vu from recent days. Is this an educational assignment somewhere?